# Parse XML file for value based on key 'text' from batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, command-line, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML(TestResult.xml is the name of the XML file) file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<test-run id="0" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="94" result="Failed" total="90" passed="89" failed="1" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="220" engine-version="3.11.1.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" start-time="2020-08-31 09:57:53Z" end-time="2020-08-31 10:00:06Z" duration="132.798955">
```

I want to extract the *values* of the *keys* - result, total, passed, failed from the Xml. I am able to achieve that using the below batch script.

```
FOR /F tokens^=8^,10^,12^,14^ delims^=^" %%A in ('find "test-run" TestResult.xml') do (
    echo: Result:%%A, TotalTestCases:%%B, Passed:%%C, Failed:%%D
)
```

I have achieved the result using tokens based on the position(8^,10^,12^,14^) of the key/value in the xml. But the positions get changed at regular upgrades. So I want to fetch the same values based on the Key text.

help me fetch those values based on key text instead of the key/value position.
I am just new to build script and need some direction in this way.

Comment: Batch files were never designed to parse text within files, especially those which predominantly use characters which are considered 'special' or 'poisonous' to the parser. I would strongly advise you to use another scripting language for your task instead. [tag:Powershell], for instance, has built-in support for parsing [tag:xml] files.

Comment: If part of your job, VSanka, is to parse XML files, and your organization cannot allow you to use a tool which can do that, then you need to inform them that you cannot adequately perform your tasks. There is no reason why [tag:WSH] or [tag:PowerShell], which are both built-in to your Operating System, cannot be used for tasks for which they are better suited. In addition, both can be ran, without issue, directly from or within a [tag:batch-file] too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple method work with your data:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('find "test-run" TestResult.xml') do set "line=%%a"
set "line=%line:* =%"
set "var="
for %%a in (%line:~0,-1%) do (
   if not defined var (
      set "var=%%a"
   ) else (
      set "!var!=%%~a"
      set "var="
   )
)

echo: Result:%result%, TotalTestCases:%total%, Passed:%passed%, Failed:%failed%
```

Output:

```
 Result:Failed, TotalTestCases:90, Passed:89, Failed:1
```